# 301 Redirect issues

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect

Spent several hours trying to find the right answers... and testing codes..

Just switched my site from Dreamweaver html site to a wordpress site to keep up with the Google mobile restrictions. I now need to create 301 redirects for individual pages, however the redirects are to a subdomain with pages generated automatically through an IDX provider (real estate).

For example I want to 301 redirect one page:

- `http://example.com/Andalucia_Homes_for_Sale.html`

to

- `http://search.example.com/i/andalucia-apollo-beach-florida`

using the htaccess file.